# Trim the names in the list using Groovy

Tags: list, groovy, replace, trim

I have a list in `Groovy` which contains the names in the below format:

- My_name_is_Jack
- My_name_is_Rock
- My_name_is_Sunn

How can I trim the list and get only the last part of it; i.e. Names - `Jack, Rock and Sunn`. (Please note that the names are only 4 characters long)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with either one of the approach.

- You can use sustring with `lastIndexOf`
- or `replace` method to remove `My_name_is_` with empty string

Script (using the first approach):

```
def list = ['My_name_is_Jack', 'My_name_is_Rock', 'My_name_is_Sunn']
//Closure to get the name
def getName = { s -> s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('_')+1, s.size()) }
println list.collect{getName it}
```

If you want to use `replace`, then use below closure.

```
def getName = { s -> s.replace('My_name_is_','') }
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/Q4xPBR)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
def list = ['My_name_is_Jack', 'My_name_is_Rock', 'My_name_is_Sunn']

println list*.split('_')*.getAt(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the common prefix:

```
def names = [ "My_name_is_Jack", "My_name_is_Rock", "My_name_is_Sunn", ]

assert ['Jack', 'Rock', 'Sunn'] == names*.replaceFirst('My_name_is_','')
```

or since you are actually interrested in the last four chars, you can also take those:

```
assert ['Jack', 'Rock', 'Sunn'] == names*.getAt(-4..-1)
```